# Clarification of the proof of a theorem: Triangle inequality

Tags: proof-verification

First: My proof of the triangle inequality:
If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

> Proof:
>   Consider the 4 cases:

---

1) $a<0$ and $b<0$
2) $a>0$ and $b<0$
3) $a>0$ and $b>0$
4) $a<0$ and $b>0$

$$1. |-a - b| \leq |-a| + |-b| = |a| + |b|$$
$$2. |a - b| \leq |a| + |-b| = |a| + |b|$$
$$3. |a + b| \leq |a| + |b| = |a| + |b|$$
$$4. |b - a| \leq |b| + |-a| = |a| + |b|$$

Hence $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

---

I believe that is a sufficient proof. My lecturer did a different proof, which didn't really seem to make any sense to me. This is the proof exactly as was written:

Proof:
$|a+b|^2 = (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2|a||b| = (|a|+|b|)^2$
From one of our theorems of ordered fields, we know $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

That is where he accepted that it was proven, however it seems to me that he used the theorem to prove the theorem. Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Note he had the exact same thing written at the top as I did:
Theorem : If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

Comment: The last sentence is not an assumption; it is the conclusion. The last step of the proof comes from the fact that $x^2\le y^2$ implies $x\le y$ when $x,y\ge 0$.

Comment: @user11977 That makes sense. He is not native to English, I assume that is why it was phrased as such. Thank you.

Comment: Note also that in what you did, the extreme right expressions should be $|a|+|b|$. Otherwise equality will not hold, e.g. in case $1$.

Comment: @Macavity Yes this is also true. Good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof which you have completed should have utilised $\leq$ rather than $<$ to justify the inequality.

Your instructor was using the fact that $\forall\ a,b$, $|ab|\leq |a||b|$ and the remainder of the proof is just manipulation of different inequalities. He is not using the statement of the theorem at any point.